# When I minimize the screen, the html page is limited and the divs slide

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am having this problem for the 2nd time. At first I thought it was because I was a rookie (I'm new to this field) when I asked the employees at work and they couldn't figure it out (I work as an intern). The problem is that when I decrease the height, the height occupied by the html page changes, but the items inside the divs try to overflow. I have difficulty in describing the problem, but it will be more meaningful with pictures.

Normal page without problem:

[image: normal page without problem]

Problem:

[image: problem]

Continuation of problem:

[image: continuation of the problem picture]

As can be seen from the pictures, how can this be possible or how can I solve it.

```js
let weather = {
  apiKey: "f2b412c0e169b2dbc28e13691fcf8c6b",
  fetchWeather: function(city) {
    fetch(
        "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q=" +
        city +
        "&units=metric&appid=" +
        this.apiKey
      )
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => this.displayWeather(data));
  },
  displayWeather: function(data) {


    for (i = 0; i <= 24; i += 8) {
      if (i == 0) {
        const {
          name
        } = data.city;
        let {
          icon,
          description
        } = data.list[i].weather[0];
        const {
          temp
        } = data.list[i].main;
        const {
          dt_txt
        } = data.list[i];

        if (icon == "01n") {
          icon = "01d";
        } else if (icon == "02n") {
          icon = "02d";
        } else if (icon == "10n") {
          icon = "10d";
        }


        document.querySelector("#city").innerText = "Weather in " + name;
        document.querySelector("#icon").src = "https://openweathermap.org/img/wn/" + icon + "@2x.png";
        document.querySelector("#description").innerText = description;
        document.querySelector("#temp").innerText = temp.toFixed(2) + "°" + "C";
        document.querySelector("#day").innerText = String(new Date(dt_txt)).slice(0, 3);
        document.querySelector("#Date").innerText = String(dt_txt).slice(0, 10);

        //Sunny
        if (icon == "01d" || icon == "01n") {
          ChangeBgSunny();

          function ChangeBgSunny() {
            console.log('geldi');
            const images = [
              'url("sunny/1.jpg")',
              'url("sunny/2.jpg")',
              'url("sunny/3.jpg")',
              'url("sunny/4.jpg")',
              'url("sunny/5.jpg")',

            ]
            console.log('geldi2');

            const main = document.querySelector('#main');
            const bg = images[Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length)];
            main.style.backgroundImage = bg;

          }
        }
        //Rainy
        else if (icon == "10d" || icon == "09d" || icon == "09n") {
          ChangeBgRainy();

          function ChangeBgRainy() {
            console.log('geldi');
            const images = [
              'url("rain/1.jpg")',
              'url("rain/2.jpg")',
              'url("rain/3.jpg")',
              'url("rain/4.jpg")',
              'url("rain/5.jpg")',

            ]
            console.log('geldi2');

            const main = document.querySelector('#main');
            const bg = images[Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length)];
            main.style.backgroundImage = bg;

          }
        }
        //Cloud
        else if (icon == "02d" || icon == "03d" || icon == "03n" || icon == "04d" || icon == "04n") {
          ChangeBgcloud();

          function ChangeBgcloud() {
            console.log('geldi');
            const images = [
              'url("cloud/1.jpg")',
              'url("cloud/2.jpg")',
              'url("cloud/3.jpg")',
              'url("cloud/4.jpg")',
              'url("cloud/5.jpg")',

            ]
            console.log('geldi2');

            const main = document.querySelector('#main');
            const bg = images[Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length)];
            main.style.backgroundImage = bg;

          }
        }



      } else if (i == 8) {
        const {
          name
        } = data.city;
        let {
          icon,
          description
        } = data.list[i].weather[0];
        const {
          temp
        } = data.list[i].main;
        const {
          dt_txt
        } = data.list[i];

        if (icon == "01n") {
          icon = "01d";
        } else if (icon == "02n") {
          icon = "02d";
        } else if (icon == "10n") {
          icon = "10d";
        }


        document.querySelector("#icon1").src = "https://openweathermap.org/img/wn/" + icon + "@2x.png";
        document.querySelector("#day1").innerText = String(new Date(dt_txt)).slice(0, 3);
        document.querySelector("#temp1").innerText = temp.toFixed(2) + "°" + "C";
      } else if (i == 16) {
        const {
          name
        } = data.city;
        let {
          icon,
          description
        } = data.list[i].weather[0];
        const {
          temp
        } = data.list[i].main;
        const {
          dt_txt
        } = data.list[i];

        if (icon == "01n") {
          icon = "01d";
        } else if (icon == "02n") {
          icon = "02d";
        } else if (icon == "10n") {
          icon = "10d";
        }


        document.querySelector("#icon2").src = "https://openweathermap.org/img/wn/" + icon + "@2x.png";
        document.querySelector("#day2").innerText = String(new Date(dt_txt)).slice(0, 3);
        document.querySelector("#temp2").innerText = temp.toFixed(2) + "°" + "C";
      } else if (i == 24) {
        const {
          name
        } = data.city;
        let {
          icon,
          description
        } = data.list[i].weather[0];
        const {
          temp
        } = data.list[i].main;
        const {
          dt_txt
        } = data.list[i];

        if (icon == "01n") {
          icon = "01d";
        } else if (icon == "02n") {
          icon = "02d";
        } else if (icon == "10n") {
          icon = "10d";
        }


        document.querySelector("#icon3").src = "https://openweathermap.org/img/wn/" + icon + "@2x.png";
        document.querySelector("#day3").innerText = String(new Date(dt_txt)).slice(0, 3);
        document.querySelector("#temp3").innerText = temp.toFixed(2) + "°" + "C";
      }
    }





  },
  search: function() {
    this.fetchWeather(document.querySelector(".search-item").value);
  },
};

document.querySelector(".button").addEventListener("click", function() {
  weather.search();
});

document.querySelector(".search-item").addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
  if (event.key == "Enter") {
    weather.search();
  }
});

weather.fetchWeather("Istanbul");
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Gill Sans', 'Gill Sans MT', Calibri, 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif;
}

.search-item {
  color: gray;
  font-size: 20px;
  background-color: black;
  width: 30%;
  height: auto;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 30px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  transition: width 2s;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.search-item:focus {
  width: 90%;
  background-color: white;
}

.button {
  margin-left: 10px;
  border-radius: 30px;
  color: gray;
  background-color: black;
  width: 20%;
}

.days {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

#Days:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

#search-main:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

#input {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

#main {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  padding: 20px 100px 20px 100px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
}

#weather {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  margin-top: 1%;
  margin-bottom: 1%;
  margin-left: 1%;
  margin-right: 1%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border-radius: 30px;
}

#search-main {
  width: 70%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  border-radius: 30px;
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
  opacity: 0.7;
}

#Days {
  width: 30%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  opacity: 0.8;
  border-radius: 30px;
}

#description {
  text-transform: capitalize;
}

@media screen and (max-width:950px) {
  #main {
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    padding-right: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
  }
  #Days {
    position: absolute;
    visibility: hidden;
  }
  #weather {
    width: 100%;
    margin-right: 10%;
    margin-left: 10%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="main">

  <div id="weather">
    <div id="search-main">
      <div id="input">
        <input class="search-item" type="text" placeholder="Search City"><button class="button"><i class="fas fa-search fa-lg" style="color: white;"></i></button>
      </div>
      <div>
        <h1 id="day"></h1>
      </div>
      <div>
        <h3 id="Date"></h3>
      </div>
      <div>
        <h2 id="city"></h2>
      </div>
      <h1><img src="" id="icon"></h1>
      <div>
        <h1 id="temp"></h1>
      </div>
      <div>
        <h1 id="description"> </h1>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="Days">
      <div id="First-day" style="opacity:1;">
        <h1><img src="" id="icon1" style="opacity:1 !important;"></h1>

        <div class="days">
          <h2 id="day1"></h2>
        </div>
        <div>
          <h1 id="temp1"></h1>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="Second-day">

        <h1><img src="" id="icon2"></h1>

        <div class="days">
          <h2 id="day2"></h2>
        </div>
        <div>
          <h1 id="temp2"></h1>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="Third-day">
        <h1><img src="" id="icon3"></h1>

        <div class="days">
          <h2 id="day3"></h2>
        </div>
        <div>
          <h1 id="temp3"></h1>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, I tried to put your code into some sandbox ( https://bold-exuberant-sword.glitch.me/ ) but wasn't successful in reproducing the issue. Please put everything into the fiddle directly in the question together with missing assets. In case if it's possible to reproduce it with the mentioned sandbox, let me know what steps must be done - I would be happy to help

Comment: ow when you said it, I realized that the places of the codes have slipped, I am correcting them immediately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add overflow: hidden to both the divs (#search-main and #Days) like [Wiktor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6110804/wiktor) mentioned.
Further, as the overflowed data is not visible, you can try these.

As you can see from the below image, the reason you see some white space below is because, after you have reduced the width, the visibility of the right div #Days is set to hidden in the media queries.

Now when you are reducing the height, the right div is still present there, just not visible. The items inside the right div is causing the overflow.

So in the media queries, instead of **visibility:hidden**
You can do **display:none**

```
  #Days {
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
  }
```

display: none; will completely remove the div instead on hiding it.

[image]

Now, when you continue to reduce the height of the window, you will still see the items are getting overflowed from the div causing white space below because we didn't do anything to prevent the overflow.

The items inside the divs #search-main and #Days are overflowing because there is no space left between those elements.
The empty space you see is occupied by the images that are 100px x 100px.

[image]

So what you can do is instead of setting
**height: 100%**
add **min-height: 100%**
to both the divs

```
#search-main {
  width: 70%;
  min-height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  border-radius: 30px;
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
  opacity: 0.7;
}

#Days {
  width: 30%;
  min-height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  opacity: 0.8;
  border-radius: 30px;
}
```

Setting min-height: 100% will not allow the items to overflow from it's parent div.

If you don't want the divs to overflow its parent or from body. You have to keep the height of the child divs less than or equal to the parent div.

Comment: Very professional and explanatory answer. Thank you so much

Comment: Thanks. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

I think what is happening, is that your `#Day` element is too big - bigger than the rest of the page. Because of absolute positioning, it overflows the html tag but it cannot overflow #document giving it a true height, and a scrollbar. I have tried adding  `overflow: hidden` to `#Day` and it fixed the issue. The same goes for `#search-main`

```js
let weather = {
        apiKey:"f2b412c0e169b2dbc28e13691fcf8c6b",
        fetchWeather: function(city){
            fetch(
                "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q="
                + city
                + "&units=metric&appid="
                + this.apiKey 
            )
            .then((response)=> response.json())
            .then((data)=>this.displayWeather(data));
        },
        displayWeather: function(data){
    
            
            for(i=0;i<=24;i+=8)
            {
                if(i==0)
                {
                    const {name} = data.city;
                    let {icon, description} = data.list[i].weather[0];
                    const {temp} = data.list[i].main;
                    const {dt_txt} = data.list[i];
    
                    if(icon == "01n")
                    {
                        icon = "01d";
                    }
                    else if(icon=="02n")
                    {
                        icon = "02d";
                    }
                    else if(icon=="10n")
                    {
                        icon="10d";
                    }
                    
    
                    document.querySelector("#city").innerText = "Weather in " + name;
                    document.querySelector("#icon").src = "https://openweathermap.org/img/wn/"+icon+"@2x.png";
                    document.querySelector("#description").innerText = description;
                    document.querySelector("#temp").innerText = temp.toFixed(2)+"°"+"C";
                    document.querySelector("#day").innerText = String(new Date(dt_txt)).slice(0, 3);
                    document.querySelector("#Date").innerText = String(dt_txt).slice(0, 10);
    
                    //Sunny
                    if(icon == "01d" || icon == "01n")
                    {
                        ChangeBgSunny();
    
                        function ChangeBgSunny(){
                            console.log('geldi');
                            const images =[
                                'url("sunny/1.jpg")',
                                'url("sunny/2.jpg")',
                                'url("sunny/3.jpg")',
                                'url("sunny/4.jpg")',
                                'url("sunny/5.jpg")',
                        
                            ]
                            console.log('geldi2');
                            
                            const main = document.querySelector('#main');
                            const bg = images[Math.floor(Math.random()*images.length)];
                            main.style.backgroundImage = bg;
                        
                        }
                    }
                    //Rainy
                    else if(icon=="10d" || icon=="09d" || icon=="09n")
                    {
                        ChangeBgRainy();
    
                        function ChangeBgRainy(){
                            console.log('geldi');
                            const images =[
                                'url("rain/1.jpg")',
                                'url("rain/2.jpg")',
                                'url("rain/3.jpg")',
                                'url("rain/4.jpg")',
                                'url("rain/5.jpg")',
                        
                            ]
                            console.log('geldi2');
                            
                            const main = document.querySelector('#main');
                            const bg = images[Math.floor(Math.random()*images.length)];
                            main.style.backgroundImage = bg;
                        
                        }
                    }
                    //Cloud
                    else if(icon=="02d" || icon=="03d" || icon=="03n" || icon=="04d" || icon=="04n")
                    {
                        ChangeBgcloud();
    
                        function ChangeBgcloud(){
                            console.log('geldi');
                            const images =[
                                'url("cloud/1.jpg")',
                                'url("cloud/2.jpg")',
                                'url("cloud/3.jpg")',
                                'url("cloud/4.jpg")',
                                'url("cloud/5.jpg")',
                        
                            ]
                            console.log('geldi2');
                            
                            const main = document.querySelector('#main');
                            const bg = images[Math.floor(Math.random()*images.length)];
                            main.style.backgroundImage = bg;
                        
                        }
                    }
                
                
    
                }
                else if(i==8)
                {
                    const {name} = data.city;
                    let {icon, description} = data.list[i].weather[0];
                    const {temp} = data.list[i].main;
                    const {dt_txt} = data.list[i];
    
                    if(icon == "01n")
                    {
                        icon = "01d";
                    }
                    else if(icon=="02n")
                    {
                        icon = "02d";
                    }
                    else if(icon=="10n")
                    {
                        icon="10d";
                    }
    
                   
                    document.querySelector("#icon1").src = "https://openweathermap.org/img/wn/"+icon+"@2x.png";
                    document.querySelector("#day1").innerText = String(new Date(dt_txt)).slice(0, 3);
                    document.querySelector("#temp1").innerText = temp.toFixed(2)+"°"+"C";
                }
                else if(i==16)
                {
                    const {name} = data.city;
                    let {icon, description} = data.list[i].weather[0];
                    const {temp} = data.list[i].main;
                    const {dt_txt} = data.list[i];
    
                    if(icon == "01n")
                    {
                        icon = "01d";
                    }
                    else if(icon=="02n")
                    {
                        icon = "02d";
                    }
                    else if(icon=="10n")
                    {
                        icon="10d";
                    }
    
                    
                    document.querySelector("#icon2").src = "https://openweathermap.org/img/wn/"+icon+"@2x.png";
                    document.querySelector("#day2").innerText = String(new Date(dt_txt)).slice(0, 3);
                    document.querySelector("#temp2").innerText = temp.toFixed(2)+"°"+"C";
                }
                else if (i==24)
                {
                    const {name} = data.city;
                    let {icon, description} = data.list[i].weather[0];
                    const {temp} = data.list[i].main;
                    const {dt_txt} = data.list[i];
    
                    if(icon == "01n")
                    {
                        icon = "01d";
                    }
                    else if(icon=="02n")
                    {
                        icon = "02d";
                    }
                    else if(icon=="10n")
                    {
                        icon="10d";
                    }
    
                    
                    document.querySelector("#icon3").src = "https://openweathermap.org/img/wn/"+icon+"@2x.png";
                    document.querySelector("#day3").innerText = String(new Date(dt_txt)).slice(0, 3);
                    document.querySelector("#temp3").innerText = temp.toFixed(2)+"°"+"C";
                }
            }
    
            
    
            
    
        },
        search: function(){
            this.fetchWeather(document.querySelector(".search-item").value);
        },
    };
    
    document.querySelector(".button").addEventListener("click", function(){
        weather.search();
    });
    
    document.querySelector(".search-item").addEventListener("keyup",function (event){
        if( event.key == "Enter")
        {
            weather.search();
        }
    });
    
    weather.fetchWeather("Istanbul");
```

```css
*{
        margin:0;
        padding: 0;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        font-family: 'Gill Sans', 'Gill Sans MT', Calibri, 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif;
    }
    
    .search-item
    {
        color: gray;
        font-size: 20px;
        background-color: black;
        width: 30%;
        height: auto;
        padding: 10px;
        border-radius: 30px;
        border: 1px solid gray;
        transition: width 2s;
        text-overflow: ellipsis;
        
    }
    .search-item:focus
    {
        width: 90%;
        background-color: white;
    }
    
    .button
    {
        margin-left: 10px;
        border-radius: 30px;
        color: gray;
        background-color: black;
        width: 20%;
    }
    .days
    {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
    }
    
    #Days:hover
    {
        opacity: 1;
    }
    
    #search-main:hover
    {
        opacity: 1;
    }
    
    #input
    {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
    }
    
    
    #main
    {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100vh;
        padding: 20px 100px 20px 100px;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: center;
        background-size: cover;
    }
    
    
    #weather
    {
    
        width: 50%;
        height: 100%;
        margin-top: 1%;
        margin-bottom: 1%;
        margin-left: 1%;
        margin-right: 1%;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
    
        border-radius: 30px;
        
    }
    #search-main
    {
        width: 70%;
        height: 100%;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        justify-content: space-around;
        align-items: center;
        border-radius: 30px;
        color: white;
        overflow: hidden;
        background-color: black;
        opacity: 0.7;
    }
    
    #Days
    {
        width: 30%;
        height: 100%;
        display: flex;
        overflow: hidden;
        flex-direction: column;
        justify-content: space-around;
        align-items: center;
        background-color: black;
        color: white;
        opacity: 0.8;
        border-radius: 30px;
    }
    #description
    {
        text-transform: capitalize;
    }
    @media screen and (max-width:950px)
    {
        #main
        {
            padding-top: 20px;
            padding-bottom: 20px;
            padding-right: 0;
            padding-left: 0;
    
        }
        #Days
        {
            position: absolute;
            visibility: hidden;
        }
        #weather
        {
            width: 100% ;
            margin-right: 10%;
            margin-left: 10%;
    
        }

    }
```

```html
    <div id="main">

        <div id="weather">
            <div id="search-main">
                <div id="input">
                    <input class="search-item" type="text" placeholder="Search City"><button class="button"><i class="fas fa-search fa-lg" style="color: white;"></i></button>
                </div>
                <div>
                   <h1 id="day"></h1>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <h3 id="Date"></h3>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <h2 id="city"></h2>
                </div>
                <h1><img src="" id="icon"></h1>
                <div>
                    <h1 id="temp"></h1>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <h1 id="description"> </h1>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="Days">
                <div id="First-day" style="opacity:1;">
                    <h1><img src="" id="icon1" style="opacity:1 !important;"></h1>

                    <div class="days">
                        <h2 id="day1"></h2>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <h1 id="temp1"></h1>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="Second-day">
                    
                    <h1><img src="" id="icon2"></h1>

                    <div class="days">
                       <h2  id="day2"></h2>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <h1 id="temp2"></h1>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="Third-day">
                    <h1><img src="" id="icon3"></h1>

                    <div class="days">
                        <h2 id="day3"></h2>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <h1 id="temp3"></h1>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```